Fermi energy of $N$ fermion on a circular ring
I have two questions.
1.) We know that in a one-dimensional problem the energy levels of a bound state system are discrete and not degenerate. (zettili).
But in case of one dimensional particle on a ring energy eigenvalues are:
$$E_n=\frac{n^2 h^2}{2 m L^2}$$
where $R$ is the radius of the ring  and $L = 2\pi R$ and $n$ belongs to the set of integer therefore for $n=1$ and $n=-1$ give us the same energy eigenvalue. Why is that so? Is it related to the boundary condition for particle on the ring.
2.) This is related to the Fermi energy. What is the Fermi energy of a $N$ spinless fermions on ring of circumference $L$? My guess is:
$$\frac{N^2h^2}{8mL^2}$$

$n=\pm |n|$ just have the particles moving  with velocity $\pm \hbar n/m$ either clockwise or anticlockwise round the ring. Same speed $\Rightarrow$ same energy.

Answers to your questions:
1.) The reason why $n=1$ and $n=-1$ give the same energy eigenvalue arises due to the symmetry of this instance. The ring's circular nature allows for clockwise and counterclockwise motion. Therefore, the wavefunctions that corresponds to $n$ and $-n$ are:
$$
\psi_1(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}x}
$$
$$
\psi_{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{L}x}
$$
Whereas both wavefunctions satisfy the same periodic boundary conditions and have the same energy level.
2.) Your guess was very close but there is a small algebraic error. For semplicity sake (we can further expand on more complicated situations if you want) let's consider $N$ fermions to be even, which will have $n=\pm\frac{N}{2}$ as the highest occupied state; this leads us to defining the Fermi energy $E_F$ as the following:
$$
E_F=\frac{(\frac{N}{2})^2h^2}{2mR^2} = \frac{N^2h^2}{8mR^2}
$$
Since we have $L=2\pi R$, $R$ can be expressed as $\frac{L}{2\pi}$:
$$
E_F = \frac{N^2h^2}{8m(\frac{L}{2\pi})^2}=\frac{N^2h^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}
$$
Leading us to the final result. I hope I answered your questions as you wanted, hit me up to refine anything if you need! Have a good studying session :)))

The energy eigenvalues are $$ E_n=\frac{n^2\hbar^2}{2mR^2}$$. Now lowest state has energy 0 which corresponds to n=0.and remaining energy eigenvalues are doubly degenarate meaning two eigenstates giving same energy eigenvalue when we apply the Hamiltonian of the system mentioned in the question on them.for N =2n there will be one vacant shell (draw the pictures of the energy levels with degenaracy for your convenience and we shall fill all levels at T=0K until we run out of particles the energy of topmost filled level is the Fermi energy level with $$ \frac{N^2\pi ^2 \hbar
^2}{2mL^2}$$
